# Icenium Mist - Can't Run Simulator in Chrome (Script Error)

Tags: icenium

This used to work for me, but now whenever I attempt to "Run in Simulator" with any of the iPhone or iPad types selected, I instantly get the console message

2013/10/1 10:4:48 Error: Script error. (URL: , LineNumber: 0)

I am working in the latest version of Chrome.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In fact, I get the same error just by clicking the "Version Control" button.

Answer (score 1):

Just so that other users are aware, you can get that error on almost any problem in Mist and identifying the cause usually requires that we (I'm part of Icenium team) look into the specific project. In this particular case the problem was caused by missing App_Resources folder, which blaster has removed from his repository prior cloning it in Icenium. Generally an Icenium project should be able to function without this folder and we would fix this for the next version.